# How to 'skip' and 'include' subdocuments with mongoose query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

Let's say I have this structure

```
    Account { 
       Id, 
       Name, 
       Password, 
       Details { 
                  LastSignedIn, 
                  CreatedDate
                  Address { 
                            City, 
                            Country
                          } 
               }
        }
```

`Details` subdocument belongs to `Account`, `Address` subdocument belongs to `Details`

With `mongoose` can I say to retrieve the particular subdocument or skip the other one with findqueries?

Something like:

```
//will return in result 'Account' with only 'DetailsSubdocument' included
Account.findOne({name:'user'}, include: {'Account.DetailsSubdocument'}) 

//will return in result 'Account' with only 'AddressSubdocument' included
Account.findOne({name:'user'}, include: {'Details.AddressSubdocument'})

//will return in result 'Account' both two subdocuments included
Account.findOne({name:'user'}, include: {'Details.AddressSubdocument', 'Account.DetailsSubdocument'})
```

Comment: How is DetailsSubdocument linked to `Account`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills just updated

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are going for since `Details` contains `Address` but it seems like you can do this with projection (second argument to `.findOne` as in `.findOne({name:'user', {"Details.LastSignedIn": 1, "Details.CreatedDate": 1})` for the first, and then `{"Details.Address": 1}`, and just `{"Details": 1}` to include everything.